# angular 4 how set order statements running?

Tags: angular

```
public onSubmit(formLogin:NgForm):void
{
  router:Router;
   this.SearchDosService.getLogin(formLogin).subscribe(data => this.array = data);//I LOGIN HTTP GET       
   this.router.navigate(['./home']);//II NAVIGATE
}
```

in action in form submission :
command II run and finish before command I .
How can I specify a order to solve it .(queuee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the router.navigate code inside the subscribe logic

```
public onSubmit(formLogin: NgForm): void {
    router: Router;
    this.SearchDosService.getLogin(formLogin).subscribe(data => {
        this.array = data;
        this.router.navigate(['./home']);
    });
}
```